# using Fill in different timeframes

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

i've an Ichimoku Indicator.
I add the following arguments to `indicator()` function.

```
indicator(title='Ichimoku Kinkō Hyō', overlay=true, timeframe='', timeframe_gaps=true)
```

This allow me to change the timeframe calculation in the script

[image]

The trouble is when i select a 1 Hour timeframe on mine chart, and 4 Hours on indicator.
Ichimoku is calculated on Higher Timeframe (4h in this case) but the cloud is not colored, or better, is just partially colored.

How is possibile to color completely?

This is what im trying to fix, seems the `fill()` function use the 4h bar instaed of each one:
[image]

and that's whats i would like appear indipendently of which timeframe i select on indicator:
[image]

if i deselect the "Gaps" checkbox. they looks really horrible.
[image]

Any suggestion?

Full Script (based on default ichimoku indicator):

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Ichimoku Cloud", shorttitle="Ichimoku", overlay=true, timeframe='', timeframe_gaps=true)
conversionPeriods   = input.int(9, minval=1, title="Conversion Line Length")
basePeriods         = input.int(26, minval=1, title="Base Line Length")
laggingSpan2Periods = input.int(52, minval=1, title="Leading Span B Length")
displacement        = input.int(26, minval=1, title="Lagging Span")

donchian(len) => math.avg(ta.lowest(len), ta.highest(len))

conversionLine = donchian(conversionPeriods)
baseLine       = donchian(basePeriods)
leadLine1      = math.avg(conversionLine, baseLine)
leadLine2      = donchian(laggingSpan2Periods)

plot(conversionLine, color=#2962FF, title="Conversion Line")
plot(baseLine, color=#B71C1C, title="Base Line")
plot(close, offset = -displacement + 1, color=#43A047, title="Lagging Span")

p1 = plot(leadLine1, offset = displacement - 1, color=#A5D6A7,title="Leading Span A")
p2 = plot(leadLine2, offset = displacement - 1, color=#EF9A9A,title="Leading Span B")

plot(leadLine1 > leadLine2 ? leadLine1 : leadLine2, offset = displacement - 1, title = "Kumo Cloud Upper Line", display = display.none) 
plot(leadLine1 < leadLine2 ? leadLine1 : leadLine2, offset = displacement - 1, title = "Kumo Cloud Lower Line", display = display.none) 
fill(p1, p2, color = leadLine1 > leadLine2 ? color.rgb(67, 160, 71, 90) : color.rgb(244, 67, 54, 90))
```

Comment: it is hard to help you without your code...

Comment: Yep sorry, mainly is identical at the default ichimoku indicator, but yeah! i added the full source code